# Automate new route to far network on new PPTP connection

Tags: server, vpn, pptp

When editing `chap-secrets`, I can assign an ip address to the account. One of the things that I notice is that, when a new connection is made, the PPTP server automatically creates a route to that ip.

What I need though, is a route to the far network and not just to the far router, so I was wondering if I could configure `chap-secrets` to accept connections from a network, instead of a single ip, so that the route would be configured accordingly, but values like `192.168.1.0/24` or other attempts don't seem to be accepted.

Is there a way to do that automatically?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible directly, because PPP is point to point protocol, i.e. allow connections between two peers only. For this to work, the distant should be configured as a gateway from your server to the far network, but you can't do that remotely through ppp.

You have to set the route explicitly on both computers in another way (iproute2 or iptables for instance).

HTH